# SQL Server - numeric and float data types

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble getting accuracy to as many decimal places as possible. If I cast 6 different numbers as `numeric(36,18)`, then do calculations between them, the resulting value is cut off at 6 decimal places. If I use float, I can go much further, but from what I hear those are cut off as well.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Show your schema and code.

Comment: why do you think that results is cut off at 6 places? maybe your output cuts it, but actual value is correct?

Comment: This is not a SQL Server issue.  You need to search the Web for the many articles that explain the behaviours of,  differences between, and relative merits of Fixed Point data types (`NUMERIC`) and Floating Point data types (`FLOAT`).  These behaviours exist across languages and is extremely valuable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> precision of the result: [p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)] ->
>   36-18+18+max(6,18+36+1)=36+55=91 scale of the result : [max(6, s1 + p2
>   + 1)] -> max(6,18+36+1)=55 In this situation precision is greater than 38 and in this case (as stated in the documentation)
>
> *The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is
>   reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.
>
> scale must be reduced by (91-38=) 53, that is (55-53=) 2 ...
>   minimum scale length is 6 (because of expression
>   scale=[max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)]) and it can't be reduced lower than 6 -
>   that we have as a result

Answer (score 0):

The things could be tricky, depending on the order of calculations.

Consider the variables:

```
DECLARE @A as NUMERIC(36,19) = 100
DECLARE @B as NUMERIC(36,19) = 480
DECLARE @C as NUMERIC(36,19) = 100
```

**Calculating A/B*C**

If you want to calculate A/B*C, using the formulaes (@Dudi answer), we have:

A/B is of type NUMERIC(38,6)

The result will be 0.208333 (with scale of 6) Multiplying by 100, we will get 20.833300

**Calculating A*C/B**

The result of A*C is 10000 of type NUMERIC(38,6). Diving by C, the result will be 20.833333 of type NUMERIC(38,6)

Then, the result may vary depending on the order of calculation (the same problem was pointed in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4878)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had no idea how complicated this can be.